# Express 4.14 - How to send 200 status with a custom message?

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse

How can I send status and message in express 4.14?

For:
res.sendStatus(200);

I get OK on my browser but I want it to display a custom message such as:
**Success 1**

```
res.sendStatus(200);
res.send('Success 1');
```

Error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

If I do [this](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send):

```
res.status(200).send(1);
```

Error:

> express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status)
>   instead

Any ideas?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use:

```
res.status(200).send('some text');
```

if you want to pass number to the send method, convert it to string first to avoid deprecation error message.

the deprecation is for sending status directly inside send.

```
res.send(200) // <- is deprecated
```

**BTW** - the default status is 200, so you can simply use res.send('Success 1').
Use .status() only for other status codes

Comment: you will get `express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead` see my edit above thanks.

Comment: Please read my response, It will only happend when passing number to send()

Comment: res.status(304).send("No changes made"); returns only the status code and not the message. Also, res.status(200).send("Not modified") works nicely, any idea why?

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't be getting that last error if you're using that exact code:

```
res.status(200).send('Success 1')
```

My guess is that you're not using the string *"Success 1"* but a numerical variable or value instead:

```
let value = 123;
res.status(200).send(value);
```

That *would* trigger the warning. Instead, make sure that `value` is stringified:

```
let value = 123;
res.status(200).send(String(value));
```

Comment: *let message = "Record Inserted Successfully..."; res.status(200).send(message);*